# Significance of trackedProperties_NAME_g and trackedProperties_NAME_s in Azure Logic-app trackedProperties?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

**Sometime we queries at one and get the value at another column, so thought of sharing this finding came across**

I have created a logic-app, with trackedProperties "**MessageId**" and attached with Log analytics workspace (Diagnostic settings).

[How to add track properties to log analytics workspace in logi-app](https://www.tech-findings.com/2019/10/getting-started-with-logic-apps-what-happened-to-request.html)

```
  "trackedProperties": {
                       "MessageId": "@{json(xml(triggerBody())).ABC.DEF.MessageID}"
                       }
```

When I queried in Log Analytics,there I saw 2 trackedProperties columns with the name **trackedProperties_MessageId_g** and **trackedProperties_MessageId_s**.

**Significance of above said 2 column names:** When you provide a GUID value, it populates to **trackedProperties_MessageId_g** and when you provide string it populates to **trackedProperties_MessageId_s**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your finding(s). Yes, AFAIK when you send particular field/column to Log Analytics its name is changed based on the type. This is true for almost any field/column. However there are some fields/columns which are called reserved that you can send without name change if you send them in the right type of course. An MVP, Stanislav Zhelyazkov has covered this topic [here](https://cloudadministrator.wordpress.com/2017/05/24/reserved-common-fields-in-log-analytics/).

If you are not expecting 2 trackedProperties with the names trackedProperties_MessageId_g and trackedProperties_MessageId_s and were expecting only 1 trackedProperty then I suggest you to share your feedback in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics) UserVoice / feedback forum. Responsible product / feature team would check feasibility on how this can be resolved by adding some kind of checkpoint in the background and then if it's really feasible to accomplish then responsible product / feature team would triage / start  prioritizing the feedback based on various factors like number of votes a feedback receives, priority, pending backlog items, etc.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!


I think, the properties_id is created when the first value is encountered.
Suppose, if the first value is encountered as GUID then it creates "trackedProperties_MessageId_g" and if later, it encounters string value then it generates "trackedProperties_MessageId_s".

If above is the case then I am okay with it.